# Create a multiple plot distibution of many variables into one

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a dataframe like this:

```
structure(list(b1_previous = c(0.26981640312419, 0.302252978236613, 
    0.27519244423907, 0.278573602172958), b2_previous = c(0.165541492443112, 
    0.162543532408399, 0.150484069110868, 0.212810080358854), b3_previous = c(0.698096408083222, 
    0.625412783031095, 0.699099484936941, 0.610794910230257), b4_previous = c(0.156164414439798, 
    0.189265950612553, 0.151656203861282, 0.211930979296043), b5_previous = c(0.384820854982136, 
    0.364443743167243, 0.352744936715994, 0.397252245652394), b1_next = c(0.290892287578753, 
    0.279948606399405, 0.262591995672118, 0.327138300630022), b2_next = c(0.170072244074521, 
    0.190821283262141, 0.136632592108377, 0.185400160041476), b3_next = c(0.637122860008791, 
    0.595805110056691, 0.713976579846045, 0.594306130039334), b4_next = c(0.154789410213351, 
    0.185512865305938, 0.136271935262096, 0.18347290001916), b5_next = c(0.359935532588727, 
    0.391256325582968, 0.352913994612688, 0.312475345723399), before = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), after = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
    ), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000003d1ef0>)
```

I try to create into one graph all distibutions of the 10 variables.

How is it possible to make it?

Here a general example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Build Poisson distributions

p_dat <- map_df(1:10, ~ tibble(
  l = paste(.),
  x = 0:20,
  y = dpois(0:20, .)
))

# Build Normal distributions

n_dat <- map_df(1:10, ~ tibble(
  l = paste(.),
  x = seq(0, 20, by = 0.001),
  y = dnorm(seq(0, 20, by = 0.001), ., sqrt(.))
))

# Use ggplot2 to plot

ggplot(n_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = p_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  labs(color = "Lambda:") +
  theme_minimal()
```

using tidyverse and ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options to display all 20 distributions (10 variables each with a poisson and normal distribution). First add a distribution id (column 'd') and row bind the two datasets together:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Build Poisson distributions

p_dat <- map_df(1:10, ~ tibble(
  l = paste(.),
  x = 0:20,
  y = dpois(0:20, .),
  d = "pois"
))

# Build Normal distributions

n_dat <- map_df(1:10, ~ tibble(
  l = paste(.),
  x = seq(0, 20, by = 0.001),
  y = dnorm(seq(0, 20, by = 0.001), ., sqrt(.)),
  d = "norm"
))

all_dat <- rbind(p_dat, n_dat)
```

and then [facet within the ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html). 
Option 1:

```
ggplot(all_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = p_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  labs(color = "Lambda:") +
  theme_minimal()+
  facet_grid(factor(l, levels = 1:10) ~d)
```

[image]

Option 2:

```
ggplot(all_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = p_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  labs(color = "Lambda:") +
  theme_minimal()+
  facet_grid(d~factor(l, levels = 1:10))
```

[image]

Option 3:

```
ggplot(all_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = p_dat, aes(x, y, color = factor(l, levels = 1:10))) +
  labs(color = "Lambda:") +
  theme_minimal()+
  facet_grid(~d)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Actually I would like to use the input I provide, the code is just for example of the expected output